# Can I call a static method of a class by its name?

Tags: c++, reflection, static-methods

I have a bunch of classes with the same static method name, `parse`. I want to create a general function that calls `parse` for a generic class.

Can I call the method using the string name of the class, or can I pass the class as a function parameter?

Comment: You certainly can, using template meta-programming; but I am afraid you're thinking about some kind of runtime reflection like in Java/C#, which is simply not possible in C++.

Comment: Can't really pass a class in C++. There are some template games you can play, but you may be better off going old school and passing a pointer to the static method. Need more information on what you want to achieve to know for sure.

Comment: Well the level of reflection he is talking about (calling a function by name) is obviously possible in C++. Anyway, if he has to ask about that, I wouldn't recommend going that route. Why not just have a common interface to all those classes like IParser { virtual void parse() = 0; } and have each class implement IParser. Then your generic function will be simply void Parse(IParser& p); or w/e you need.

If you need something else, you need to be more specific on how you want such thing to work.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very broad in my opinion. I am not sure what exactly you are after but here are some options:

Have a common interface like IParser that all subclasses must implement (in this case a method Parse). You can than have one function that takes IParser&.

If you are really after the 'call by name' like some sort of RPC than I would suggest another approach where you have to register functions manually into a map of some sort that takes a pointer to the function as value, and name of the class as key. Than calling this function is as easy as `map[fnName]();`

Answer (score 0):

C++ has no built-in reflection mechanism. If you are interested in calling method by its string representation you need to take care of `name -> method pointer` mapping by yourself. In this case the `std::unordered_map`, `std::string` and `std::function` might be helpful.

An exemplary c++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> functions;
    static void bar() {
       std::cout << "Foo::bar called" << std::endl;
    }

    static void init() {
        functions["bar"] = &Foo::bar;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(void)> Foo::functions;

int main() {
    Foo::init();
    Foo::functions["bar"]();
}
```

However if you are not interested in calling method by string only you want to call specific method of given name you could play with templates:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    static void bar() {
       std::cout << "foo::bar called" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct tag{};

template <class T>
void call_bar(tag<T>) {
    T::bar();
}

int main() {
    call_bar(tag<foo>{});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need to use the [scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) :: to qualify the method with the name of the class that exposes it:

Class::Method();

Comment: Not the downvoter but he's not simply asking 'how do you call a static function'